# Update a column based on two multiplied columns of different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

I am working on a car rental assignment.

The part I am stuck on is updating the `Amount_Due` of `TRANSACTIONS_TEST` table, based on the total cost.

The total cost is calculated by multiplying `Price` in the `CAR_TEST` table, by the total days between `TRANSACTIONS_TEST.PickupDate` and `TRANSACTIONS_TEST.ReturnDate`.

I am unsure of how to correctly join both tables/columns to calculate this.

Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE CAR_TEST 
(
    carID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Make varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    Model varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    Type varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    Year char(4) NOT NULL,
    Price int NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE TRANSACTIONS_TEST 
(
    tID int PRIMARY KEY,
    cID int REFERENCES CUSTOMER_TEST(cID),
    carID int REFERENCES CAR_TEST(carID),
    eID int REFERENCES EMPLOYEE_TEST(eID),
    tDate date NOT NULL,
    PickupDate date NOT NULL,
    ReturnDate date NOT NULL,
);
```

Here is my confused attempt at trying to do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TRANSACTIONS_TEST, CAR_TEST
WHERE CAR_TEST.carID = TRANSACTIONS_TEST.carID

UPDATE TRANSACTIONS_TEST
SET Amount_Due = (DATEDIFF(DAY, PickupDate, ReturnDate) * CAR_TEST.Price)
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show some sample data and the desired results (as formatted text).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: `Year char(4) NOT NULL` Nope - start over. Year is a 4 digit number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a join in the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE tt
SET tt.Amount_Due = DATEDIFF(DAY, tt.PickupDate, tt.ReturnDate) * ct.Price
FROM TRANSACTIONS_TEST tt INNER JOIN CAR_TEST ct
ON ct.carID = tt.carID
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for commenting. When seeing similar questions on other posts I couldn't quite get my head around it. This has really helped me understand how this works. Thanks again!